# Angular 7 - Error when building component library with ngTemplateOutlet

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular7

I've just upgraded to Angular 7 and I'm struggling to get my component library to compile correctly.

I have the following code:

auto-complete.component.html:

```html
<li *ngFor="let item of items; let index = index;">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="listItemTemplateRef.template, context: { $implicit: item, index: index }"></ng-container>
</li>
```

In my auto-complete.component.ts, I have this line:

```js
@ContentChild(AutoCompleteListItemTemplateDirective) listItemTemplateRef: TemplateRef<AutoCompleteListItemTemplateDirective>;
```

and an auto-complete-list-item-template.directive.ts file:

```js
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[autoCompleteListItemTemplate]'
})
export class AutoCompleteListItemTemplateDirective {
    @Input() type: string;
    @Input('autoCompleteListItemTemplate') name: string;

    constructor(public template: TemplateRef<any>) { }
}
```

And finally the page that is consuming my component:

```html
<ng-template let-result [autoCompleteListItemTemplate]>
    <span style='font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;'>{{result.company}}</span><br />
    <span>{{result.name.first}} {{result.name.last}}</span><br />
</ng-template>
```

When I run this in my test project, it all works fine.  However, when I try and ng build my component library for release, I get the following error:

```
Property 'template' does not exist on type 'TemplateRef<AutoCompleteListItemTemplateDirective>'.
```

Ok, I remove that from the component html and try this:

```
*ngTemplateOutlet="listItemTemplateRef, context: { $implicit: item, index: index }"
```

This compiles, but whenever I try and render anything, I get this runtime error:

```
templateRef.createEmbeddedView is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you went wrong with the correct type for `ContentChild`:

```
@ContentChild(...) listItemTemplateRef: TemplateRef<AutoCompleteListItemTemplateDirective>
                                                    ||
                                                    \/
@ContentChild(...) listItemTemplateRef: AutoCompleteListItemTemplateDirective
```

And bring back the template to:

```
*ngTemplateOutlet="listItemTemplateRef.template
```